# Add whitespace after character in the TextField

Tags: ios, xcode6, uitextfield

I am creating SDK in which user needs to enter 4 digit PIN and there should be space after each character and textfield should be secureTextEntry  enabled .I am writing following  code

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

   NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                             withString: string];


     if (text.length < 13)
    {
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@  ", text];

        return NO;
    }

    return newLength <= 12;


}
```

but the problem is as I am adding space between character space is also shown as dot . This solution works fine in non SDK code . I am trying hard to find the any easy solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

         NSUInteger length = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

      if (length < 10) {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *lastString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[newString characterAtIndex:newString.length-1]];

   if(![lastString isEqualToString:@" "] && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
       newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
   else {

       NSRange tempR = NSMakeRange(range.location-1, 2);

       newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:tempR withString:@""];
   }

   textField.text = newString;
  }

return NO;
```

}

Comment: The code which I mention is also working fine when textfield.secureTextEntry = NO  but when we make textfield.secureTextEntry = YES.Then issue rises the blank space which we added with text is also is shown as in form of DOT as other text are shown .